# linking up Angular and Node.js: the function of .json()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I'm following a tutorial and there is a part in my server side code that I do not really understand. It sends back a response to the Angular service file on the client side but I don't understand why I need the .json() part here:

```
return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
```

Could someone please explain this to me?

**Server side route file**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Message = require('../models/message');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   // if we don't pass any arguments this means 'find all messages'
    Message.find()
        .exec(function(err, messages){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message:"'Success",
                obj: messages
            });
    });
});

router.post('/', function (req,res,next){
    var message = new Message({
        content: req.body.content
    });
    message.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            // this object is what we'll receive in the front-end
            // and what we'll convert using the response.json() method
            obj: result
        })
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You can send different types of responses with express. `.json` is just one of the options you can send via a response. Its just a JSON object. Check out the documentation for response http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: Angular usually uses AJAX to communicate with the server, which means angular and the server are basically texting each other. `.json()` is used to respond with a textual representation of the object, which is parsed and processed by Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.json` sets the body of the response as the JSON serialized version of the Javascript object you give in arguments.

Otherwise, if you simply omitted it, there would be nothing in the body of the response (just headers, including status code).

You could also set the body of the response by other means. But the JSON format is the standard way of exchanging information with Angular, and simple to use with node.js, so it is usually the obvious choice.